# Pandas apply function - comparing each row to entire column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

First time posting; apologies for formatting errors. I am attempting to count all the records in my (much larger) dataframe in a given category that are within a set amount of time of other records in that category.

The `groupby` function makes sense, but I'm having trouble defining the appropriate apply function. I've seen examples using multiple columns as inputs to a function, and others using `axis=1` to look at individual rows, but haven't seen a description of using both the entire column (to look for matches) and the entry for the row in question (to determine the time range).

I also looked at using pd.TimeGrouper to group the records by both category and time, but this can miss edge cases.

Finally, splitting by category may make each group small enough to directly iterate over, but I'd like to learn the Pythonic way, if possible.

Sample Code:

```
data = [{'xfrm':'a', 'time':10}, 
        {'xfrm':'a', 'time':12}, 
        {'xfrm':'a', 'time':20},
        {'xfrm':'b', 'time':7}, 
        {'xfrm':'b', 'time':8}, 
        {'xfrm':'b', 'time':15},
        {'xfrm':'c', 'time':2}, 
        {'xfrm':'c', 'time':8}, 
        {'xfrm':'c', 'time':15}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df
```

For each record, count all records for the same transformer within some time (e.g. 2 seconds)

```
answerData = [{'xfrm':'a', 'time':10, 'num':2}, 
        {'xfrm':'a', 'time':12, 'num':2}, 
        {'xfrm':'a', 'time':20, 'num':1},
        {'xfrm':'b', 'time':7, 'num':2}, 
        {'xfrm':'b', 'time':8, 'num':2}, 
        {'xfrm':'b', 'time':15, 'num':1},
        {'xfrm':'c', 'time':2, 'num':1}, 
        {'xfrm':'c', 'time':8, 'num':1}, 
        {'xfrm':'c', 'time':15, 'num':1}]
answerDF = pd.DataFrame(answerData)
print answerDF


# Grouping works fine
gb = df.groupby('xfrm')
for name, group in gb:
    print name
    print group
```

EDIT: I think something along these lines may work, but I'm not sure what the appropriate way to reference the time columns to replace "XXXXXX" should be.

```
def getMatches(x, potentials):
    """Applied to the group of restores attributed to meters associated with a particular transformer. 
    Checks each to see how many in the total set are within the time window. """
    matches = 0
    for time in potentials:
        if abs(timedelta(x - time).seconds) < 1200:
                matches += 1
    return matches

detailRestoreDF.groupby('category')['timestamp'].apply(getMatches,args=(XXXXXX,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really nice but gives the desired output:

```
def func(t):
    res = [0] * len(t.time)
    for i, x in enumerate(t.time):
        for y in t.time:
            if abs(x - y) <= 2:
                res[i] += 1
    t['num'] = res
    return t
print(gb.apply(func))
```

Output:

```
   time xfrm  num
0    10    a    2
1    12    a    2
2    20    a    1
3     7    b    2
4     8    b    2
5    15    b    1
6     2    c    1
7     8    c    1
8    15    c    1
```

Not sure if I understand what you looking for. But you can access a column inside an `apply` function. For example, this calculates how many rows inside a group have times less than 12:

```
>>> gb.apply(lambda x: len(x[x.time < 12]))
xfrm
a    1
b    2
c    2
dtype: int64
```

Or in the open range `6 < time < 12`:

```
>>> gb.apply(lambda x: len(x[(6 < x.time) & (x.time < 12)]))    xfrm
a    1
b    2
c    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This functionality makes sense - you can use an apply to compare each element to a fixed value (in your example, `x<12` and `6<x<12`). What I am looking for would need to, for each element, compare to all the other elements and return the number matching the closeness criterion.

Comment: Added a version that might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks - the iterative method is functional, but pushes the boundaries of acceptable speed.

Comment: To continue - I think it is O(n^2), as it needs to compare each value to all other values. I had hoped using a grouping criterion that produces a greater number of smaller segments to apply the function to would speed up the calculation, but this doesn't seem to be the case in practice. Any idea whether this is a fundamental misunderstanding, or just issues with the implementation?